# Reddit Style Voting from Mobile to server

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

I am planning a application in which a local server has a list of items, and a mobile user has an app that downloads that list. The mobile user can then upvote or downvote a list item, and only once. I plan to code this in HTML5 and JavaScript. I'm a bit new to servers and stuff, so I am wondering about the best method to go about doing this as far as the mobile user getting the list view, and returning votes.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to decode your server depending on the scalability of your project.

[Tomcat Apache](http://tomcat.apache.org/) may be used for lower number of connections to server while for higher scalability [Glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net/) server can be used.

[Differences in Glassfish and Tomcat](http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/GlassFish_vs_Tomcat)

EDIT:

To learn restful web services [see tutorial](http://rest.elkstein.org/)

[Installing Apache and axis on eclipse](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-apacheaxis/section3.html)

Comment: Wow, that is way beyond my understanding of web servers. Is there something more simple that just talks between the server and mobile device?

Comment: I think you want to create web service on a local server.In that case you can use tomcat-apache as it integrates with eclipse and then you can create restful web services and simply access from mobile using url .you will also have to use axis 2.0 as tomcat operates with this.

Comment: Ok, I'll probably come back to this later, because first I need to learn about restful web services. This turned out to be more complicated than I thought